# Android Uiautomator problem about instance selector and dump

Tags: android, dump, android-uiautomator

When I use UIautomator and I want to locate widget by instance and class
now I dump the xml like

```xml
<>
 <> systemui textview
 <> current app text view (target)
<>
```

That's to say, the dump info include some system ui node
so target instance should be 1, but actually it is 0
why

is sys ui will be ignore?